# How to pass options to ssh proxy command?

Tags: ssh, scp, proxy, options

To collect some data from a bunch of hosts I use a `bash` script which calls `scp` in a loop. Most of these hosts are configured for `ssh` public key authentication.
I may skip those which have no key authentication and ask for password, `ssh`/`scp` options do the job:

`-o BatchMode=yes`
or
`-o PasswordAuthentication=no`

But there are also hosts for which `ssh` proxy should be used, as it's set up in

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

`ProxyCommand /usr/bin/ssh -qW %h:%p <jumphost>`

In such a case any `ssh`/`scp` options apply only to the first command and I still get a password prompt from the proxy command.

Is it possible to pass options to the proxy command (without editing the configuration file)?

Comment: I do not think so. But you can have host-specific `ProxyCommand(s)`.

Comment: By "without editing the configuration file", do you really mean this? Or maybe "without altering and possibly breaking the configuration for everything else"? Even if the former, there's `ssh -F` that allows you to pass a config file tailored to the task. Can you use it?